# Move an Image continously in Random position within the display in android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-intent, android-animation

Can anyone help me to do this.
I am trying to build an android app but stuck in between.

i have use the following code to move a image.
iv is ImageView object

```
moveImage = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDest, 0, -yDest);
moveImage.setDuration(1000);
moveImage.setFillAfter( true );
iv.startAnimation(moveImage);
```

code:

```
public class gameLogic extends Activity 
{
ImageView image;
TranslateAnimation moveImage;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_logic);
    imageMoveRandom(imageList(image,0));
}

ImageView imageList(ImageView v,int i)
{
    v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rabbit);
    int imgId;
    int j = i;

    TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_imgs);
    //get resourceid by index

    imgId = imgs.getResourceId(j, 0);
    // or set you ImageView's resource to the id
    v.setBackgroundResource(imgId);

    return v;

}

void imageMoveRandom(ImageView iv)throws NotFoundException
{
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );

    int xDest = dm.widthPixels/2;
    int yDest = dm.heightPixels/2;

//      Toast.makeText(gameLogic.this, dm.widthPixels, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //      Toast.makeText(this, dm.heightPixels, 2000).show();


        moveImage = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDest, 0, -yDest);
        moveImage.setDuration(1000);
        moveImage.setFillAfter( true );
        iv.startAnimation(moveImage);
        //moveImage.reset();
    }
}
```

Above is not full code..but part which may be helpful for references.

But i want to continuously move the image in random place but within the android display.
Can any one suggest the solution.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: do you find nay solution for that?

Comment: @Chetan I'm also looking...Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -3):

```
 class BitmapView extends View
 {
   changingX=10;
   changingY=10;
   public BitmapView(Context context) {
        super(context);
   }
   @Override
   public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourImageName);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, changingX,changingY, null);
    changingX=changingX+5;
    changingY=changingY+10;
    invalidate();
   }
}
```

Try this

Comment: thanks!!! but can you provide the change in above code with AnimationTranslation ..because i have been in middle of app and i can't change it as it will affect other code..
  
Below code:   

void imageMoveRandom(ImageView iv)throws NotFoundException
 {
  DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
  this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );

  int xDest = dm.widthPixels/2;
  int yDest = dm.heightPixels/2;

   
   moveImage = new TranslateAnimation( 0, 0, 0, -yDest);
 moveImage.setDuration(1000);
 moveImage.setFillAfter( true );
   iv.startAnimation(moveImage);   
}
}

Comment: write this code to your question by editing it.put all your java code here.